# Having Rich Text in Google Forms

Tags: google-forms

In my Google Form, I have a question whose answer will be free text. But I want user to be able to format the text if needed, especially add bullets and numbering.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Google Forms doesn't have this as built-in feature and can't be easily added. If you only need numbered and bulleted list, include instructions to use 1., 2., etc for numbered lists and -, * or Unicode symbols for bulleted lists.

Answer (score 0):

enable Number lock, hold down Alt and type 0149 or 8268

•   • Circle bullet
‣   ‣ Triangle bullet
⁃   ⁃ Hypen bullet
⁌   ⁌ Leftwards bullet
⁍   ⁍ Rightwards bullet
◘   ◘ Inverse bullet
◦   ◦ White bullet
⦾   ⦾    White Point bullet
⦿   ⦿    Black Point bullet